# SSIS breaks when attempting to execute psftp.exe gives result 1

Tags: ssis

I have psftp.exe installed on my server, and am using it to obtain files via sftp to be ingested into my sql server.  I am using psftp.exe from the putty site to obtain it:

```
GET ZIP FILES:Error: In Executing "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\psftp.exe"
"XXXXXX@sftp1.XXXX.com -pw XXXXX -be -batch -b "D:\Code\XXXXX\XXXXXX.bat"" at 
"D:\Data\ZIPFOLDER", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".
```

The this works while in SSDT with no problems...however, when called by SQLSERVERAGENT on SQL SERVER, it fails.

to attempt to repair the issue, I have given `NT SERVER\SQLSERVERAGENT` full permissions on `C:\Program Files\Putty\` and my Data drive `D:` where all of my code and data storage rests.

My problem is that while I think exit code `1` means a SFTP error (is it?) how do I troubleshoot?

Thanks.

## UPDATE #1

as per instructions given by sandeep rawat, I added a windows user with administrative privileges and full control over the code and data sections of the server.

In addition, I created credentials associated with this use, and assigned a proxy user to those credentials.

Lastly, I reset the runas section in SQL SERVER AGENT's primary job to that proxy user.

Plus the setting in Internet Options.
I am still getting the same response.

THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of issue generally happens when sql AGENT  try to launch the DOS window which is the reason for the package to hang. and fails.

1 Change  **Window style** property to hidden in **process tab**

[image]

2  Give the cmdExec permission to your SQL Agent account.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/

3 Add the local drive to your trusted Intranet Sites by opening Internet Explorer and go to Internet Options > Security > Click Local Intranet > Sites and add your drive location as shown below

[image]

Comment: Than you sandeep.  can you please expand on step 2?  how do I grant SQSERVERAGENT access to cmd_exec?  Thanks